# Contentful sorting references by date in the admin

Tags: contentful

Let say I have a page content type. And this page has a field for a list of references (events in my case). By default, Contentful let me order them manually (drag and drop). But these events have a date and I would find more practical that they are ordered by date automatically instead.

Is there a way to do this?

IMPORTANT NOTE: I don't mean sorting in a query. I know how to do this. I mean the order inside Contentful when we edit. This is actually one of Contenful's weak point for me. As a developer I'd like tailor a little bit more what the end editor will see, especially on the "content" landing page.

Comment: You could create an extension: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/extensibility/

Comment: @thchp Thank you. I've considered this route but it feels quite overkill for such a basic feature.